# Does apktool create the R.class?

Tags: android, apktool

I decompile an apk by using

```
apktool d -d myapp.apk
```

then I add a png image in res/drawabe
and finally I recompile the apk with a "apktool b"

But actually I think that my picture is not mapped in the R file (something like 0x000001), and the resource R.drawable.myimage is not found

Is it possible to tell to apktool to map the picture ? What would be the apktool commandline ?

Thanks

Comment: Even if apktool regenerated the R.java file, then you **wouldn't have assigned your drawable to any control**... so it's completely useless.

Comment: Ok, so I just want to replace an image already assigned. Is it possible, just by changing the image in my drawables folders ?

Comment: Yes, it is. If you are **replacing** an existing image, and use the **same file name**, you can do it. R doesn't change.

Answer (score 4):

Nope

apktool d decode resource.ascr into res/values/public.xml and decode R.classes into R.smalis

apktool b just build the res/values/public.xml into resource.ascr file

the mapping is not changed at all all the mapping information is in  public.xml and R.smalis and a lot of ids are complied into the smali code

You can do the mapping manually

I have done this it really works!

trust me we have it running in the production environment

But it is really alot of work